# Avoiding overload hell with c# 4.0

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I am using C# 4.0, how can I avoid the problem of writing lots of similiar methods because they are each parameter-unique (how can the new parameter features avoid overload hell?).

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
void Method(string param1, string param2) { }
void Method(string param1, string param2, string param3) { }
void Method(string param1, string param2, string param3, string param4) { }
void Method(string param1, string param2, string param3, int int4) { }
//etc...
```

You can just have one method with all the params you want, and call it using the named params like this:

```
void Method(string param1, string param2 = "default2", 
            string param3 = "default3", int int4 = 12, int lastParam = 12) { }
```

And call it like this:

```
Method(param1: "myString", int4: 23);
//or...
Method(param1: "myString", param4: "string2", int4: 23);
```

Just include what you want to set, the rest will be the defaults you specified in the method signature.

Comment: I think the syntax does not have braces.

Comment: @Martinho - Woops was answering a javascript object question at the same time :) fixed

Comment: What if the method uses all the parameters and I attempt to only pass in some of them?

Comment: @dotnetdev - Give defaults to all the ones you *may* not pass, and those defaults will be used/passed into the method whenever you don't specify that particular parameter, even if that default is `null`.

Answer (score 6):

Assume you have a class Employee as mentioned below which has 3 constructors.

```
public class Employee
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Qualification { get; set; }
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }

    public Employee(string firstName, string lastName)
    {
        FirstName= firstName;
        LastName= lastName;
        Qualification= "N/A";
        MiddleName= string.Empty;
    }
    public Employee(string firstName, string lastName, string qualification)
    {
        FirstName= firstName;
        LastName= lastName;
        Qualification= qualification;
        MiddleName= string.Empty;

    }
    public Employee(string firstName, string lastName, string qualification,
        string middleName)
    {
        FirstName= firstName;
        LastName= lastName;
        Qualification= qualification;
        MiddleName= middleName
    }
}
```

With C# 4.0, you will need to create a single constructor as following which will replace all 3 constructors.

```
public class Employee
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Qualification { get; set; }
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }

    public Employee(string firstName, string lastName,
            string qualification = "N/A", string middleName = "")
    {
        FirstName= firstName;
        LastName= lastName;
        Qualification= qualification;
        MiddleName = middleName;
    }
}
```

This constructor can be called in following manners..

```
Employee emp = new Employee("Adil", "Mughal");
Employee emp = new Employee("Adil", "Mughal", middleName: "Ahmed");
Employee emp = new Employee("Adil", qualification:"BS");
Employee emp = new Employee("ABC", lastName: "EFG", qualification: "BS");
Employee emp = new Employee("XYZ", middleName: "MNO");
```

Comment: Better to show this with methods as opposed to constructors, as you can already do something like this with property initialization in C# 3.

Comment: For your first version I woul have had the constructors with fewer arguments call the constructor with more aguments passing the default values. A useless point, since the second option is nicer, but just to nit pick on a Sunday :)

Comment: In C# 3 I might have considered rewriting the method to accept a parameter collection object. Like Nick remarks, you could initialize that object conveniently using property initializers. But for C# 4.0 just using optional arguments directly in the method seems a lot more sensible.

Answer (score 3):

In C# 4.0, you can use optional parameters.

[Named and Optional Arguments (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx)